# Codeigniter 404 routing for valid function but invalid parameter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter for my ongoing project

I have created user profiles and and the url looks like following

```
mysite.com/index.php/foo/bar/P001

mysite.com/index.php/foo/bar/P002

mysite.com/index.php/foo/bar/P003
```

when I enter the following in url

```
mysite.com/index.php/foo/bar
```

it shows every profile in a page. but I want it to route to 404 page.

how can it be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be to do with the URI segments you are passing into your controller action.

- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

Are you setting default value for the parameter?

It's been a while since I've used CodeIgniter but [erhaps you need to validate the URI param to check it's value and on `null` call `show_404()` or something.

e.g.

```
public function action($param = null) {

    if ($param === null) {
        show_404()
    }

    ... 
}
```

- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: No default value, retrieved  from database

Comment: Could also be written as public function action($param=null), then if($param){

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using the routes.php in application/config

```
$route['foo/bar'] = "path/to/404";
$route['foo/bar/(:any)'] = "foo/bar/$1";
```

See more on this at

- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html